# Rounded float is returned with all decimals

Tags: rounding, floating-accuracy, wordpress-rest-api

I have a rest endpoint that returns some simple statistics: total votes, average vote,...

```
function getRatings($data) {
  global $wpdb;
  $struttura_id = intval( $data['struttura_id'] );

  $sql = " SELECT COUNT(M.meta_key) as num_votes, SUM(M.meta_value) as tot_votes
           FROM .... ";

  $stats = $wpdb->get_row($sql);

  return array('struttura_id'=>$struttura_id, 
               'num_votes' => $stats->num_votes, 
               'tot_votes'=> $stats->tot_votes, 
               'average'=> round($stats->tot_votes/$stats->num_votes,1) );
}
```

For some reason the average value is not rounded when I receive it as a REST response form WP rest API.

Response is:

```
{
  "struttura_id": 115,
  "num_votes": "3",
  "tot_votes": "10",
  "average": 3.2999999999999998
}
```

As you can see the average value is pretty "strange". Too much decimals and wrong precision (a good value should be 3.33333333)

What's wrong?

Comment: (a) I presume the `round` function, given `round(x, n)`, is intended to return `x` rounded to `n` decimal places. If so, the fact you are using `round(…, 1)` explains why the result is near 3.3 rather than 3⅓. For a more accurate result, remove `round`. (b) The floating-point format you are using represents numbers using multiples of a power of two. 3.3 cannot be exactly represented in this format; no calculation can ever produce 3.3 exactly. You must accept approximations or use a different format (which like means implementing your own, rather than using built-in language formats).

Comment: On the other hand, if you are fine with getting a value near 3.3 in the program but merely want to format it as “3.3” for display, that would be a matter of using the language’s number formatting features when preparing the output.

Comment: I solved this issue converting the value to string before passing it as a return value